# Change timezone without tzutil - Windows Web Server 2008

Tags: windows

For some reason Web does not include tzutil. You must have R2 to access this utility.

This is frustrating because I need to change the time according to different timezones.

How can I use the "time" command to change the time based on an input timezone (like GMT-6 or possibly "Central Standard Time") ?

Comment: TCCLE allows to set the time in UTC using the /U switch if this might be an option for you.

Comment: That only has the option to set to UTC time. What about other time zones?

Comment: Just forget about my comment. Whilst the `/U` option allows you to set the time in UTC - you could calculate the offset manually, it is not available in TCC/LE at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Vista and Server 2008 RTM did not ship with a way to change time zones via script. Microsoft fixed this by releasing KB2556308. This hotfix will give you the TZUtil command-line tool.

https://serverfault.com/questions/429011/change-timezone-without-tzutil-windows-web-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

If PowerShell is an option for you, you can use the `Set-Time` CmdLet, that allows you to specify the time with a timezone information.

You can find more information on the CmdLet here: [Using the Set-Date Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176960.aspx)

Along with possible values to be passed as the new time: [DateTime.Parse Method (String) (System)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

Install latest PowerShell version from Microsoft Download Center, assuming you have SP2 installed and are willing to install .NET Framework 4.0: [Download: WMF 3.0 - Microsoft Download Center - Download Details](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595)

I was able to set my time by invoking:

```
Set-Date -Date "Tue, 18 Sep 2012 09:44:00+1"
```

Might this be an option for you?